# Best path to get into natural language processing

Tags: nlp

Currently I'm a PHP programmer and I would like to know the best way to learn about NLP, from theory to practice. Doesn't matter the language.

For example:

**Theory**

1. Firt learn the Basic grammar
2. Then learn about first order logic, Description logic etc.

**Technical**

1. Learn PROLOG
2. Learn about openCyc
3. For web applications you can use prolog and python with the library pylog.

Is it possible to create a topic based tutorial?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get a good book. I recommend *Speech and Language Processing* by Jurafsky and Martin. Learn Java, or better, Python, and one or more of the many [toolkits](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/List_of_natural_language_processing_toolkits) for NLP.

If you want Prolog, try [*Prolog and Natural Language Analysis*](http://www.mtome.com/Publications/PNLA/pnla.html), but do realize that the logic-oriented approach has almost entirely gone out of favor in the last two decades because it proved too brittle and too expensive. Statistical methods and machine learning are everything now, and approaches that combine logic and statistics are really cutting-edge research.

Comment: I first looked at PROLOG due to this project: http://attempto.ifi.uzh.ch/site/description/ which is very interesting. But then I so NLTK for python. So is NLTK the best choice?

Comment: @Keyne: that project is aimed at [controlled natural language](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Controlled_nature_language), which is useful for natural language generation but not very much for processing actual text. NLTK is nice if you want do NLP in Python. Check out their [free textbook](http://www.nltk.org/book).

Answer (score 3):

[Get your hands dirty](http://www.nltk.org/).

Comment: Um, not really anymore. I was considering grad school for NLP in college; I was a language major. I have a bunch of books in my apartment. If you want, I can update with a list of some of them if you are truly interested. Please check out NLTK, since it has implementations of almost everything useful or something you will learn. If you already a programmer, learn by example. Also, Jursfasky's book mentioned by @larsmans is considered a definitive source. It was going to be at the top of that list.

Comment: I'm truly interested! I've found this http://www.nltk.org/book which is very handy. Please, post the titles when possible.